# How do i get a Teamviewer ID in C#?

Tags: c#, events, registry

I've asked this question before, but I'm trying to get a Teamviewer ID from the registry and display it in a messagebox when a button has been clicked, However when I click said button, a blank message box pops up and I would like some help resolving this issue.

my code for retrieving the Teamviewer ID is below;

```
public static string CollectTeamviewerId()
        {
            var versions = new[] { "4", "5", "5.1", "6", "7", "8" }.Reverse().ToList();

            foreach (var path in new[] { "SOFTWARE\\TeamViewer", "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\TeamViewer" })
            {
                if (Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path) != null)
                {
                    foreach (var version in versions)
                    {
                        var subKey = string.Format("{0}\\Version{1}", path, version);
                        if (Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subKey) != null)
                        {
                            var clientID = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subKey).GetValue("ClientID");
                            if (clientID != null)
                            {
                                return clientID as string;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

and for the button;

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(LogDataFactory.CollectTeamviewerId());
        }
```

Comment: Obvious first question... If you browse to that Registry location does the key exist and does it contain a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code `clientID as string` to `clientID.ToString()` as `clientID` in registry is *DWORD*  type and  `clientID as string` will always be `null`:

```
if (clientID != null)
{
      return clientID.ToString();
}
```

**Edit:** 
you can check out `as` keyword [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

> if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception